# Extending value range in gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot

I see that something fails above 100^4

```
gnuplot> print 100 ** 4
100000000
gnuplot> print 100 ** 5
1410065408
gnuplot> print 100 ** 6
-727379968
```

Negative numbers is not something that I expect when raising into the power. How can I support numbers that large?

Comment: What version of gnuplot are you using and what OS?  I am not seeing that on windows with either 5.0 (64bit) or 4.6 (32bit).  This likely is caused by integer overflow.

Comment: That bug was fixed long time ago, at least since 4.6.0. Now gnuplot automatically switches to double when it runs into integer overflow. Or, if you have such large values, use `100.0**6`

Comment: https://sourceforge.net/p/gnuplot/bugs/820/

Comment: @all I do not know the version of my gnuplot. I cannot find the command to check it.

Comment: That tells you the startup message when you call gnuplot. Or, on the command line type `gnuplot --version`, or, when you are in interactive mode type `show version`.